# Adding a custom annotation to Android Saripaar

Tags: android, validation, user-interface, saripaar

I just started using android saripaar library for a client's app. I wanted to add a custom validation for a field. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to create a custom annotation. I have to manually put in rule in the validator.

How do I create a custom annotation for the same?

Comment: I'm working on Saripaar v2 and it supports custom annotations. Will post an answer when it's ready.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

(Disclosure: I'm the author)

[Saripaar v2](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) allows you to define custom annotations.

Here's how you do it.

**Step 1** Define your custom annotation as follows. Make sure you have a `RUNTIME` retention policy and your annotation must be targeted towards `FIELD` element types. The `message` and `messageResId` attributes are mandatory, so watch the names and the types.

```
@ValidateUsing(HaggleRule.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Haggle {
    public int messageResId()   default -1;                     // Mandatory attribute
    public String message()     default "Oops... too pricey";   // Mandatory attribute
    public int sequence()       default -1;                     // Mandatory attribute

    public double maximumAskingPrice();                         // Your attributes
}
```

**Step 2** Define your rule by extending the `AnnotationRule` class.

```
public class HaggleRule extends AnnotationRule<Haggle, Double> {

    protected HaggleRule(Haggle haggle) {
        super(haggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Double data) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        double maximumAskingPrice = mRuleAnnotation.maximumAskingPrice();

        // Do some clever validation....

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

**Step 3** Register your rule.

```
Validator.registerAnnotation(Haggle.class); // Your annotation class instance
```

Simple as that. Take a look at the source code if you want to. Saripaar v2 is now available on Maven Central.

Comment: Where is HagglingPolicy defined?

Comment: @T.Coutlakis, similified the example.

Comment: @RagunathJawahar even after going through your source code its not clear what kind of parameters the annotations are expecting can you please share a blog / article or i would really love to help you in documenting the project

Comment: Maybe you can just add the optional validator. `@OptionalEmail`

Comment: Hi Ragunath Jawahar - Thanks for these awesome lib, What i am looking for is Or validation against field means like login with pin or userId  at-least  one of them should filled and check min and max length can we do these using saripaar if yes please give me some tips thanks