# Android Saripaar v2 phone number validation?

Tags: android, validation, saripaar

How can I do validation for a phone number in [Android Saripaar v2](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar)?

Does it include a validation class for this, or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclosure: I'm the author)

Hi, phone numbers do not have a universal format and differs from region to region. So, Saripaar doesn't have any built-in validation for phone numbers. You can always create rules that serve your purpose.

To create a custom annotation, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405645/adding-a-custom-annotation-to-android-saripaar).

You can also add a [QuickRule](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/blob/master/saripaar/src/main/java/com/mobsandgeeks/saripaar/QuickRule.java) that would serve the purpose.

1. Use the `QuickRule` if you want to get the job done easily.
2. If you are looking for reusability and convenience, create a custom annotation. It is a bit more work, but pays off eventually.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I was confused after seeing `@TextRule(order = 7, message = "Enter valid Phone Number", minLength = 10, maxLength = 14)` from previous version, which didn't work in v2.