# How do you make a field an email field not required in Android Saripaar?

Tags: android, saripaar

I have a simple form in my Android app that I am using Android Saripaar to validate, one of the fields is an email address and according to [the first example in the docs](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar#quick-start) it should look something like this:

```
@NotEmpty
@Email
private EditText emailEditText;
```

However I would like it to be an optional field so I omitted the `@NotEmpty` annotation:

```
@Email
private EditText emailEditText;
```

But when I leave it empty it understandably marks it as an invalid email address. Is it possible to have this field be optional without writing a custom rule?

Comment: Looks like this is actually an [open issue](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/issues/102) on the GitHub repo

Comment: Will answer when there's a fix for that.

Comment: Great thanks! Saripaar is a fantastic tool by the way

Comment: Glad that you like it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since we needed an optional email field for a project I went ahead and made a rule/annotation combination according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405645/adding-a-custom-annotation-to-android-saripaar). Referred to Saripaar docs for [Rules](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/blob/master/saripaar/src/main/java/com/mobsandgeeks/saripaar/rule/EmailRule.java) and [Annotations](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/blob/master/saripaar/src/main/java/com/mobsandgeeks/saripaar/annotation/Email.java).

**OptionalEmailRule.java**

```
public class OptionalEmailRule extends AnnotationRule<OptionalEmail, String> {

    protected OptionalEmailRule(final OptionalEmail email) {
        super(email);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String email) {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            //email is empty and therefore valid
            return true;
        }
        else{
            //email is not empty, proceed as usual
            boolean allowLocal = mRuleAnnotation.allowLocal();
            return EmailValidator.getInstance(allowLocal).isValid(email);
        }

    }
}
```

**OptionalEmail.Java**

```
@ValidateUsing(OptionalEmailRule.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface OptionalEmail {
    boolean allowLocal()    default false;

    int sequence()          default -1;
    int messageResId()      default -1;
    String message()        default "Invalid email";

}
```

Inside Validation Activity

1. Register the Annotation

   ```
   Validator.registerAnnotation(OptionalEmail.class);
   ```
2. Annotate the field

   ```
   @OptionalEmail
   public EditText editEmail;
   ```

Comment: Great. One small suggestion: Instead of email.equals("") check you should use TextUtils.isEmpty(email)